# Docker + Marathon : how to do a port mapping ?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I am trying to launch rstudio on my infrastructure.

If I do :

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 192.168.0.38:5000/rocker/rstudio
```

Then I have rstudio running fine on my server.
But I have mesos and marathon, and would like to make a Marathon's app out of this docker command.

I can't find the way to map correctly the port.

I tried :

```
{
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "volumes": [],
  "docker": {
    "image": "192.168.0.38:5000/rocker/rstudio",
    "network": "HOST",
    "privileged": true,
    "parameters": [
      {
        "key": "p",
        "value": "8787:8787"
      }
    ],
    "forcePullImage": true
  }
}
```

Hopping that I would work, but it never starts.

And I tried :

```
{
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "volumes": [],
  "docker": {
    "image": "192.168.0.38:5000/rocker/rstudio",
    "network": "HOST",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8787,
        "hostPort": 8787,
        "servicePort": 10003,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "privileged": true,
    "parameters": [],
    "forcePullImage": true
  }
}
```

Which is not better.

Which json would you suggest me to convert this working docker command :

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 192.168.0.38:5000/rocker/rstudio
```

??

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really following what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The port mapping is (as with Docker) only relevant for `BRIDGE` networking mode, see also the [Marathon doc](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html). In your case the following should work:

```
...
"container": {
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "docker": {
    "network": "BRIDGE",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 8787,
        "hostPort": 8787
      }
    ]
  }
},
...
```

[Mesosphere doc](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/ports.html)

Comment: you can even set the hostPort as 0 to Mesos asign an automatic available port ... just in case you wan to spin more instances of the same docker image in a cluser or load balanced configuration